# Export contacts from iTunes to Google

Tags: macos, itunes, export, google-contacts

How do I export the contacts backed up in iTunes from a MacBook to a Google account?

Answer (score 1):

If your contacts show in your Mac's Address Book, you first have to select them all. Do this by pressing `⌘A`, or going to *Edit » Select All*.

Then, go to *File » Export* and select the *Export vCard…* option.

[image]

Then, save this file on your Desktop. Open up Gmail, navigate to Contacts, and select *Import* from the *more* menu.

[image]

Select your `.vcf` file that you created on your Desktop and upload it. Google will import all your contacts. Note that this will *not* synchronize contacts. You can also set up Google account synchronization from your Address Book preferences if you want.